# streaming on iOS through rtmp

Tags: ios, streaming, video-streaming, rtmp

I am desperately looking for a solution to stream through rtmp from red5 server on iOS. And I couldn't get rtmp c lib work on my Xcode project. 
Could anyone please post any tutorials? or share some other solutions maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what i found till now. 
very useful obj-c libs, but costs smt. 
- http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-mobile/universal-mobile-connectivity-overview.html
- http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-iphone-RTMP-library.shtml

Then, i tried to implement librtmp c lib. But it would take long.
-http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/librtmp.3.html

So, we decided in the end, to communicate over web sockets and stream over http.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

[Brightcove Player iOS SDK](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/mobile-sdks/brightcove-player-sdk-for-ios/index.html)